# Creating list inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I am trying to create a list inside a function, do some processing and return that list. The code goes as below:

```
def fibo(num):
    fib = [1,2]
    i =2
    while fib[-1] <int(num):
        fib = fib[i-1]+fib[i-2]
        i+=1
    return fib
```

On calling the function, I get and error saying that

```
while fib[-1] <int(num):
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is this issue being caused? Can I not create a list in a function in Python?

EDIT: I see a lot of downvotes on my question. Can someone guide me as to why my question got so many downvotes. This would help me ask the right questions and help the community :)

Comment: Think the reason you got a downvote is because your question isn't really useful for the community, if you had googled the error you probably would've found the answer almost immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `fib = fib[i-1]+fib[i-2]` by `fib.append(fib[-1] + fib[-2])` and your code will be correct.

As they mentioned in the comments, your line `fib = fib[i-1]+fib[i-2]` is transforming the list `fib` into an `int`, which you want to append to your list for the code to work correctly.

Comment: Why can't I use 
`fib[i] = fib[i-1]+fib[i-2]` ?

Comment: @SwastikMohapatra `fib[i]` can't extend the list so would be an `IndexError`, you need to `append()` or `extend()` to increase the list (there is also `slice` assignment but that is for another time). BTW: you didn't write `fib[i]` you just wrote `fib`.

Comment: You should avoid as much as possible, in python, the use of indexes (like your `i`). And, other than that, you can't increase the size of a `list` with that syntax, you will raise an error.

Comment: I see. I was under the impression that if I use `fib[i]` then Python would extend and then assign to that list.

Comment: It would be a strange behaviour. For example, if `fib` was a list of size 3, someone could try to set a value in `fib[3000]`. What should the interpreter do then? Fill thousands of values with some null value? It would be error prone and quite catatrophical for development.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want something like

```
fib.append(fib[-1]+fib[-2])
```

instead of

```
fib = fib[i-1]+fib[i-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def fibo(num):
    i =2
    fib = [1, 2]

    while fib[-1] < int(num):
        fib.append(fib[i-1]+fib[i-2])
        #fib = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]
        i+= 1
    return fib

result=fibo(9)
print(result)
```

I think the error occurs when overwriting the list.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually using `fib` which converted it into a number